# Change Order of Features in Popup with ESRI ArcGIS Javascript API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am using version 3.12 of the ESRI ArcGIS Javascript API and have noticed that the order of the features that show up in my info window popup does not correspond to the order layers those features are in. I want to be able to specify that all of the features from the same layer appear next to each other as I toggle though the selected features.

For example, say I have a map with two feature layers in the following order: 1. tax_parcels and 2. county_border. If I click on a spot within county_border where tax_parcels has overlapping features, I would expect my info window popup to show info for parcel1. When I click the next arrow I expect to see info for parcel2 and info for the county when I click next again. In my actual map in some cases I am seeing parcel1 followed by county followed by parcel2.

I found this thread: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/169793 but it did not provide any solutions. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: Did you try listening to the Popup's `on-set-features` event, and re-ordering the features? https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/popup-amd.html#event-set-features

Comment: Actually, yes, I was able to get it working using that approach. I came back to answer my question but you beat me to it. Do you want to post it as an answer?

Comment: but how to define ImportantLayer?

Comment: @ziemek In the example below, ImportantLayer is a placeholder for the id of the layer that should be on top. This id can be defined multiple ways depending on how you are creating your map/adding your layers. I suggest you ask a separate question about how to retrieve that if you need help finding it. That will allow you to provide details about how your map and layers are created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Re-order the features when the Popup's [on-set-features](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/popup-amd.html#event-set-features) event fires.

Here is a code snippet of how to do this:

```
function bindInfoWindowSortingFunction(map) {  
    require(['dojo/_base/connect'], function (connect) {  
        connect.connect(map.infoWindow, "onSetFeatures", function () {  
            var orderedFeatures = [];  
            for(var i = 0; i< map.infoWindow.features.length; i++) {  
                if (map.infoWindow.features[i]._layer.id === 'ImportantLayer') {  
                    orderedFeatures.unshift(map.infoWindow.features[i]);  
                }  
                else {  
                    orderedFeatures.push(map.infoWindow.features[i]);  
                }  
            }  
            map.infoWindow.features = orderedFeatures;  
        });  
    });  
}
```